# How can I rescue from Postgresql's COPY command when copying a large CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a feature where I am attempting to copy a very large CSV file into my database. I am using the `pg` gem to do so very quickly as explained in this article here [POSTGRESQL COPY](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/superfast-csv-imports-using-postgresqls-copy).

In my schema.rb, I have unique constraints on a model so there are times during the upload process, I'll encounter a `PG::UniqueViolation` constraint error when attempting to import a file.

What I need to do is I need to be able to capture this error and once captured, write some code that will log the error and the message along with some other details. The problem I am experiencing is that I am unable to currently capture the exception of writing the data into the file. Below is the following pseudo code:

```
db_conn.copy_data(CODE_COPY_STATEMENT, enco) do
  iterator.each do |line|
    
  .......# CODE #.......

    begin
      db_conn.put_copy_data([information_to_copy])
    rescue StandardError => e
      I need to do some stuff here for processing the error, etc.
    end
   .......# CODE #......
  end
end
```

So far I'm unable to capture the error and I've tried to capture `PG::UniqueValidation`, `StandardError` etc. but to no success. Ultimately, what I need to do is to skip over this error and continue processing the file. Does anyone have anything I can try? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't, `COPY` is al or none. The best practice is to `COPY` into a staging table that has no constraints and then move the data from there via SQL commands to the final table.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, I appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COPY` is a single statement and can only apply atomically - even if you are streaming in the data in chunks. By the time you catch the exception, the `COPY` statement has been aborted, none of the rows prior to the violation occurring will be queryable, and the `COPY` cannot be resumed. In a case where you have, say, 10 rows, and a single row causes a violation, the *only* way of getting those other 9 rows present is with an INSERT or a COPY that does *not* include the problematic row. In practice, this means using single-row inserts, possibly with [savepoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html) so you don't have to do a transaction-per-row.

Another approach you may want to consider is to COPY into a table with no constraints, use regular DML to duplicate non-violating rows into the real data, and then drop/truncate the table you used for the import.

But fundamentally, a "resumable, violation-tolerant `COPY`" just isn't a thing; the statement is the finest-grained level at which an operation can succeed or fail in PG, and COPY is still just one statement.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I appreciate it.